# AVAudioMix audio ducking not working

Tags: ios, audio, avfoundation, avplayeritem

I'm trying to do audio editing on an AVMutableComposition that I have build.

```
        var commentaryTimeRange = CMTimeRange(start: commentaryItem.startTimeInTimeline, duration: commentaryItem.timeRange.duration)
        if CMTimeCompare(CMTimeRangeGetEnd(commentaryTimeRange), composition.duration) == 1 {
            commentaryTimeRange.duration = CMTimeSubtract(composition.duration, commentaryTimeRange.start);
            commentaryItem.timeRange = commentaryTimeRange
        }
        // Add the commentary track
        let compositionCommentaryTrack = composition.addMutableTrack(withMediaType: AVMediaTypeAudio, preferredTrackID: kCMPersistentTrackID_Invalid)
        let track = commentaryItem.asset.tracks(withMediaType: AVMediaTypeAudio).first!
        try! compositionCommentaryTrack.insertTimeRange(CMTimeRange(start: kCMTimeZero, duration:commentaryTimeRange.duration), of: track, at: commentaryTimeRange.start)

        let tracksToDuck = composition.tracks(withMediaType: AVMediaTypeAudio)
        var trackMixArray = [AVMutableAudioMixInputParameters]()
        let rampDuration = CMTime(seconds: 1, preferredTimescale: 2)
        for track in tracksToDuck {
            let trackMix = AVMutableAudioMixInputParameters(track: track)
            trackMix.setVolumeRamp(fromStartVolume: 1.0, toEndVolume: 0.2, timeRange: CMTimeRange(start: CMTimeSubtract(commentaryTimeRange.start, rampDuration), duration: CMTimeSubtract(commentaryTimeRange.duration, rampDuration)))
            trackMix.setVolumeRamp(fromStartVolume: 0.2, toEndVolume: 1.0, timeRange: CMTimeRange(start: CMTimeRangeGetEnd(commentaryTimeRange), duration: rampDuration))
            trackMixArray.append(trackMix)
        }
        let audioMix = AVMutableAudioMix()
        audioMix.inputParameters = trackMixArray
```

Basically I'm truing to add a commentary on a video track by ducking the original volume.
The audio is correctly mixed in the output, but audio instructions seem to ignored.
Of course the audiomix is passed to the AVPlayerItem, from debugging I can see that all the instructions are there and correctly passed to it.

```
 func makePlayable() -> AVPlayerItem {
        let playerItem = AVPlayerItem(asset: composition.copy() as! AVAsset, automaticallyLoadedAssetKeys: NewsPlayerViewController.assetKeysRequiredToPlay)
        playerItem.videoComposition = videoComposition
        playerItem.audioMix = audioMix?.copy() as! AVAudioMix?
        if let overlayLayer = overlayLayer {
            let syncLayer = AVSynchronizedLayer(playerItem: playerItem)
            syncLayer.addSublayer(overlayLayer)
            playerItem.syncLayer = syncLayer
        }
        return playerItem
 }
```

I've found some answers that indicate as reason the lack of a track identifiers, or a sort of mismatch between composition that has one and a track that hasn't.
My composition doesn't use any track id, plus the AVEdit sample code from Apple doesn't use them and it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was simply to count the tracks to duck BEFORE adding the commentary track.

```
      let tracksToDuck = composition.tracks(withMediaType: AVMediaTypeAudio)// <- MOVE HERE, AT THE TOP

        var commentaryTimeRange = CMTimeRange(start: commentaryItem.startTimeInTimeline, duration: commentaryItem.timeRange.duration)
        if CMTimeCompare(CMTimeRangeGetEnd(commentaryTimeRange), composition.duration) == 1 {
            commentaryTimeRange.duration = CMTimeSubtract(composition.duration, commentaryTimeRange.start);
            commentaryItem.timeRange = commentaryTimeRange
        }
        // Add the commentary track
        let compositionCommentaryTrack = composition.addMutableTrack(withMediaType: AVMediaTypeAudio, preferredTrackID: kCMPersistentTrackID_Invalid)
        let track = commentaryItem.asset.tracks(withMediaType: AVMediaTypeAudio).first!
        try! compositionCommentaryTrack.insertTimeRange(CMTimeRange(start: kCMTimeZero, duration:commentaryTimeRange.duration), of: track, at: commentaryTimeRange.start)

        var trackMixArray = [AVMutableAudioMixInputParameters]()
        let rampDuration = CMTime(seconds: 1, preferredTimescale: 2)
        for track in tracksToDuck {
            let trackMix = AVMutableAudioMixInputParameters(track: track)
            trackMix.setVolumeRamp(fromStartVolume: 1.0, toEndVolume: 0.2, timeRange: CMTimeRange(start: CMTimeSubtract(commentaryTimeRange.start, rampDuration), duration: CMTimeSubtract(commentaryTimeRange.duration, rampDuration)))
            trackMix.setVolumeRamp(fromStartVolume: 0.2, toEndVolume: 1.0, timeRange: CMTimeRange(start: CMTimeRangeGetEnd(commentaryTimeRange), duration: rampDuration))
            trackMixArray.append(trackMix)
        }
        let audioMix = AVMutableAudioMix()
        audioMix.inputParameters = trackMixArray
```

Comment: Please add more details to your answer. What did you change in code. I am facing a similar issue.